# HTML input type file shorten filename

Tags: html, css

I was wondering is there a way to manipulate the size of the filename when using `<input type="file">`

Say for instance i have a file named:

> iamaverylongtextthatwilldestoryyourcssbecauseidontknowwhattocallmyfiles.txt

When using this in a browser window that is small will move buttons and other `html` tags

So if there was a way to shorten this so it takes the first 5 characters of the filename and then adds the file extension. Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting a width on the input?

Comment: Not quite as you say but you can do that with CSS by putting dots at the end

Comment: @j08691 This worked but seems kinda hacky?

Comment: Why you do not use a jquery plugin, like `dropzone` ?